# Как из iframe достать input?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Пытаюсь достать поле из iframe, но в консоль я получаю null, но поле в iframe есть. Что не так, как получить?

```
<iframe src="//1696854416.svetacdn.in/r0bcpkSqsjWe/tv-series/12785" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen></iframe>

var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
console.log(iframeDocument.querySelector('#videoType'))
```

Comment: Провкряйте по очереди, что возвращает вам каждый селектор, для начала

Comment: Попробовал body, он мне вернул <body></body>

Answer (score 1):

Если iframe не Ваш, то - никак.

В случае если Вы можете дополнить код iframe, то используйте https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage для пересылки содержимого инпута.

Comment: iframe не мой. Действительно никак нельзя этого сделать?

Comment: @user569536 Никак из-за политик безопасности

Comment: @user569536 расширение браузера создать которое будет добавлять user-script в этот фрейм